# Windows 10 cannot use 5Ghz to reach 100mbps

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, 802.11

I have upgraded my landline to get 100mbps. My router can handle it since I manage to peak at 96 with my cell phone, a OnePlus One 5T

For my PC, I bought an ASUS [PCE-AC56](https://www.asus.com/Networking/PCEAC56/) to be able to reach those speeds, but I am not reaching more than 60mps. I suspect this is because Windows is using the band 2.4Ghz

[image]

I tried to change the preferred band in the device manager, but it did not help.

[image]

What should I do to switch to 5Ghz?

**UPDATE:** I know my SSID shows the name of a router that does not support 5Ghz band. It is not the router I have anymore. The one I have now (model 7490) does support it, but I just did not want to reconfigure all my devices, so I kept the old SSID and password =P Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Does your router have a 2.4 GHz band and a 5 GHz band? You can't go into the device settings and flip to one or another. They are two separate networks from your router, and you have to connect to the one that is 5 GHz. In your screenshot, you're connected to the 2.4 GHz network.

Comment: It appears your modem is also dual-band.  Disable the 2.4 GHz network, and the 802.11ac adapter should connect to the only network that is available. This is evident by the fact 802.11ac is 5.0 GHz only, but you are connected to an 802.11n network at 2.4 GHz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect this is because Windows is using the band 2.4Ghz

Your suspicious is correct. You are connected to the 2.4Ghz band, and as such your speeds are not that high.

> What should I do to switch to 5Ghz?

First, on your router where you create the 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz wifi, make sure that both networks have UNIQUE SSID's. I recommend adding 5G in the name for the 5Ghz and optionally 2.4G on the 2.4Ghz SSID.

So for example, lets say you have named your WiFi: MyWifi, you will want to rename the 2.4Ghz to MyWifi 2.4G, and the 5Ghz to MyWifi 5G.

Now, on your pc, you should be able to see both networks as separate networks. Connect to the 5G and you're set. You can connect to both, but keep in mind that you cannot be connected to both. If for whatever reason one connection drops, your pc will likely switch to the other network. Therefor it is recommended to keep the 2.4Ghz one such that you don't remember the password. If your network disconnects then you know that you need to connect it again, something that will likely happen only once every blue moon anyway.

Alternatively you could disable the 2.4Ghz on your modem entirely, but that means you have no backwards compatible network in case anyone with a device comes in that can't connect to a 5Ghz network. Yes, they still exist.

Comment: If the author were to configure their adapter to prefer 802.11a, the SSID could be identical for both the 2.4 GHz and 5.0 GHz network, but due to 802.11a the adapter could only connect to the 5.0 GHz network (this should be the case)

Comment: @Ramhound I found out by plenty of experimentation, that it really doesn't work too well to prefer one network over the other if they have the same SSID and password. In theory it should work, but in practice, it doesn't always do unfortunately.

Comment: In the end this is the only thing it worked. Now I have 2 different SSIDs for every band.

Comment: As it should be. :) Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if possible with your WiFi card :

- Open *Settings > Network & Internet*
- Click *Change adapter options*
- Right-click the WiFi adapter and choose *Properties*
- In the *Networking* tab, click *Configure...*
- Go to the *Advanced* tab
- Click on *Preferred Band*
- Select "Prefer 5Ghz Band"
- Click *OK*

This is what it looks like on my computer:

[image]

---

Another possibility found in an
[archived article](https://web.archive.org/web/20141205162746/http://gdgtry.com/2014/11/force-asus-pce-ac68-and-other-adapters-onto-5ghz-wireless-802-11ac/),
is to disable the router's ability to connect to b/g networks,
so the only wireless network it sees are the a/c networks:

- Enter the *Advanced* tab
- Look for *Disable bands* and click it
- On the drop down list select "802.11b/g"
- Click OK

[image]

Comment: They already tried this. See the screenshot in OP's post. They mention it didn't work.

Comment: @LPChip: Not the same. My above setting is in the Advanced tab, not in the Details tab. It is reported to work better for some people, but it's up to the poster to verify on his computer.

Comment: That was indeed my "Advanced tab"

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent: The screenshot you posted was of the Details tab.

Comment: @harrymc I have updated the screenshot, to show you that it is indeed the "advanced" tab

Comment: It is a funny router, your Advanced tab doesn't look at all like my router's. I added a second possibility I found for a similar router. It might be a bit too violent (if it works).

Comment: @LPChip: You were right - I was wrong to contest your comment, confused by an over-charged Advanced tab containing items that should have been in the Details tab. Funny driver.

Comment: @harrymc don't sweat it. :) You could easily have been right. In IT Support, it is always the details that matter. :)